# Strict convexity of squared Euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that the square of the Euclidean norm is strictly convex, so:
$$||θx+(1−θ)y||^2<θ||x||^2+(1−θ)||y||^2$$
for $\theta\in (0,1)$ and $x\not =y$.

How do I prove it?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\theta\in (0,1)$ and let $x\not =y$. We have that
\begin{align*}
\theta\|x\|^2+&(1−\theta)\|y\|^2-\|\theta x + (1 -\theta)y\|^2 \\
&=\theta\|x\|^2+(1−\theta)\|y\|^2-\theta^2\|x\|^2-(1−\theta)^2\|y\|^2-2\theta (1−\theta)\langle x,y\rangle\\
&=\theta (1−\theta)\left(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\langle x,y\rangle\right)\\
&=\theta (1−\theta)\|x-y\|^2>0.
\end{align*}